# Select count of LIKE terms

Tags: sql

Given a mysql query such as this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions
WHERE questions.text LIKE "%some word%"
OR questions.text LIKE "%another word%"
OR questions.text LIKE "%yet another word%"
AND questions.field = "test"
... more WHERE conditions
```

What is the best way to return the breakdown for each `LIKE` term, rather than the rows which correspond to all three `LIKE` statements?

I know it is possible to do so by having separate `SELECT` statements for each of the `LIKE` terms, but is there any way to wrap this up into one `SELECT` statement, or something that might be a bit shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a select  case when   with the sum of matching values

```
SELECT 
    sum( case when questions.text LIKE "%some word%"  then 1 else 0 end) as  test1
  , sum( case when questions.text LIKE "%another word%"  then 1 else 0 end) as  test2
  , sum( case when questions.text LIKE "%yet another word%"  then 1 else 0 end) as  test3
WHERE questions.field = "test"
 ... more WHERE conditions
```